# Using replaceAll with Strings containing special characters in Java

Tags: java, special-characters, replaceall

Basically, this is what I'm trying to do is this:

```
String s = "to+go+la";

s.replaceAll("to+go", "");
```

which should return `"+la"`

I know that if I were to just replace the + signs, I would use `\\+`, but I'm not sure what I what to do when the signs are embeded.  Is the best answer to just remove them from both?  This will work for my purposes, but it seems like a duct tape answer.

Comment: what do you mean by embedded? Can you provide an example?

Comment: as in, the plus sign is in the middle of "to+go"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case doesn't call for a regex, so it is inappropriate to use it. It's both slower and more cumbersome. Use a plain and simple `replace` instead of `replaceAll` and you won't need to escape anything:

```
String s = "to+go+la".replace("to+go", "");
```

Answer (score 4):

> ... but it seems like a duct tape answer.

It seems like a "duct tape" answer because you haven't learned why you need to use `\+` when you are replacing just a "+" character.

The answer is that "+" is a regex metacharacter.  It means "the character or group before this may appear one or more times".

---

If you want `"to+go"` to be treated as a literal String (rather than a regex), then one way to do this is to "regex quote" it; e.g.

```
s.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("to+go"), "");
```

On the other hand, if the `+` characters are entirely irrelevant, then removing them would also work ...

Comment: No, I mean removing the plus signs out of both before trying to remove one from the other.  It works for me because I plan on taking out the plus signs eventually, but if I didn't, it would be an issue.

Comment: Thank you.  This is the exact answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
  String input = "to+go+la";
  String result = input.replaceAll("to\\+go","");
  System.out.println(result);
```

Why is this a bad pattern? Do you by embedded mean something like this?

```
 String input = "to+++go+la";
```

If so then the only thing that will change is the pattern:

```
 String result = input.replaceAll("to(\\+)+go","");
```